# Help writing a diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could someone explain to me how I could draw, using tikz, the following picture?
[image]
I have tried for many hours, but I have not achieved anything. Thanks for your help an time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi ! Could you show us what you have done so far ? Give us a MWE : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Have a look at http://www.texample.net which has a lot of TikZ examples including code. Especially http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/marketing-distribution-channel/ looks like a good start. If you then have further, specific problems just update your question here with it.

Comment: Don't worry.  @marmot will draw it for you.

Comment: @HenriMenke, this time i beat him :-). but only how to start ...

Comment: @Zarko It's also 1 in the night where marmot lives.

Comment: @HenriMenke, yes, so this time i took this advantage :-). but usually i left such question to him.

Comment: @HenriMenke Apparently marmot was a bit busy this time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 12mm, 
   box/.style = {draw, rounded corners, 
                 minimum width=22mm, minimum height=5mm, align=center},
            > = {Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]},
   bend angle = 15,
         auto = right,
                        ]
\node (n1)  [box] {text\\ text text text 1};
\node (n2)  [box, below right=of n1]    {text\\ text text 2};
\node (n3)  [box, above right=of n2]    {text\\ text text 3};
%
\draw[dotted,->] (n1) to ["label 1", swap]  (n3);
\draw[dashed,->] (n1) to [bend right, "label 2"]  (n2);
\draw[->]        (n2) to [bend right, "label 3"]  (n1);
\draw[->]        (n2) to [bend right, "label 5"]  (n3);
\draw[dotted,->] (n3) to [bend right, "label 4"]  (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

here on site is many similar questions with answers. you should fist search for similar ones and try to draw an adoption to your need. also helps reading of *tikz & pgf manual*, for start a tutorials ...

- library `arrows.meta` is for drawing arrows
- library `positioning` is for positioning of nodes
- library `quotes` is for labeling of arrows. syntax for this is `["<label text>"]`. option `swap` move label on oposite side of arrow
- option `bend right` is for bending lines (to right side)
- other should be self explanatory with above code